# Unable to get all hard disks information with kernel mode driver on windows 11

Tags: window, kernel, driver, windows-kernel

I am fairly new to kernel programming and I have a little problem getting all disk drives information like name,serialnumber from kernel mode. I use below code to get all disks symbolic links which works perfectly fine.

```
static VOID DeviceInterfaceTest_Func() {
NTSTATUS Status;
PWSTR SymbolicLinkList;
PWSTR SymbolicLinkListPtr;
GUID Guid = {
    0x53F5630D,
    0xB6BF,
    0x11D0,
    {
        0x94,
        0xF2,
        0x00,
        0xA0,
        0xC9,
        0x1E,
        0xFB,
        0x8B
    }
}; //Defined in mountmgr.h
Status = IoGetDeviceInterfaces( &
    Guid,
    NULL,
    0, &
    SymbolicLinkList);

if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status)) {
    return;
}

KdPrint(("IoGetDeviceInterfaces results:\n"));
for (SymbolicLinkListPtr = SymbolicLinkList; SymbolicLinkListPtr[0] != 0 && SymbolicLinkListPtr[1] != 0; SymbolicLinkListPtr += wcslen(SymbolicLinkListPtr) + 1) {
    KdPrint(("Symbolic Link: %S\n", SymbolicLinkListPtr));

    PUNICODE_STRING PTarget {};
    UNICODE_STRING Input;
    NTSTATUS s = 0;
    Input.Length = sizeof((PWSTR) & SymbolicLinkListPtr);
    Input.MaximumLength = 200 * sizeof(WCHAR);
    Input.Buffer = (PWSTR) ExAllocatePool2(PagedPool, Input.MaximumLength, 0);
    s = SymbolicLinkTarget( & Input, PTarget);
    if (s == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        //KdPrint(("%S\n", PTarget->Buffer));
        KdPrint(("Finished!\n"));
    }
}

ExFreePool(SymbolicLinkList);
}
```

However when i try to use InitializeObjectAttributes function to extract data of symbolic link inside for loop I checking their names with KdPrint and all them are null as a result i can't use ZwOpenSymbolicLinkObject, because when i use it i get BSOD. What am I doing wrong? Is my method valid to get disk information or I should use another method? Below is the code of SymbolicLinkTarget

```
NTSTATUS SymbolicLinkTarget(_In_ PUNICODE_STRING SymbolicLinkStr, _Out_ PUNICODE_STRING PTarget) {
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAtiribute {};
NTSTATUS Status = 0;
HANDLE Handle = nullptr;
InitializeObjectAttributes( & ObjectAtiribute, SymbolicLinkStr, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, 0, 0);
KdPrint(("Object length:%u \n", ObjectAtiribute.Length));
KdPrint(("Object name:%s \n", ObjectAtiribute.ObjectName - > Buffer));
Status = ZwOpenSymbolicLinkObject(&Handle, GENERIC_READ, &ObjectAtiribute);
if (Status != STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    KdPrint(("ZwOpenSymbolicLinkObject failed (0x%08X)\n", Status));
    return Status;
}
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(PTarget);
ULONG Tag1 = 'Tag1';
PTarget->MaximumLength = 200 * sizeof(WCHAR);
PTarget->Length = 0;
PTarget->Buffer = (PWCH)ExAllocatePool2(PagedPool, PTarget->MaximumLength, Tag1);
if (!PTarget->Buffer)
{
    ZwClose(Handle);
    return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
}
Status = ZwQuerySymbolicLinkObject(Handle, PTarget, NULL);
ZwClose(Handle);
if (Status != STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    KdPrint(("ZwQuerySymbolicLinkObject failed (0x%08X)\n", Status));
    ExFreePool(PTarget->Buffer);
    return Status;
}
return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your functions. Let start with he main one:

In `SymbolicLinkTarget()`:

```c
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAtiribute {};

InitializeObjectAttributes( & ObjectAtiribute, SymbolicLinkStr, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, 0, 0);
```

You are going to initialize `ObjectAtiribute` from `SymbolicLinkStr` (and the other parameters) but in `DeviceInterfaceTest_Func()` you actually never set `Input`  to contain a string!

```c
    UNICODE_STRING Input;
    NTSTATUS s = 0;
    Input.Length = sizeof((PWSTR) & SymbolicLinkListPtr);
    Input.MaximumLength = 200 * sizeof(WCHAR);
    Input.Buffer = (PWSTR) ExAllocatePool2(PagedPool, Input.MaximumLength, 0);
    s = SymbolicLinkTarget( & Input, PTarget);
```

### Input.Length

This is wrong:

```c
Input.Length = sizeof((PWSTR) & SymbolicLinkListPtr);
```

`Input.Length` will be set to the size of a pointer. According to the `UNICODE_STRING` ([ntdef.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntdef/ns-ntdef-_unicode_string); [subauth.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/subauth/ns-subauth-unicode_string)) the `length` is:

> Specifies the length, in bytes, of the string pointed to by the Buffer member, not including the terminating NULL character, if any.

So:

```c
size_t str_len_no_null = wcslen(SymbolicLinkListPtr); // number of chars, not bytes!
Input.Length = str_len_no_null * sizeof(WCHAR);
```

Notice the `wcslen()` is already in the init-statement of the for loop, I would train to extract it to have it in the loop body.

### Input.MaximumLength

```c
Input.MaximumLength = 200 * sizeof(WCHAR);
```

What if the string is more lager than 200 characters?

`MaximumLength` is defined as such:

> Specifies the total size, in bytes, of memory allocated for Buffer. Up to MaximumLength bytes may be written into the buffer without trampling memory.

Thus it's safe to just do:

```c
size_t max_length_bytes = Input.Length + (1 * sizeof(WCHAR)); // add room for possible null.
Input.MaximumLength = max_length_bytes;
```

The allocation for the `Buffer` member can be kept in place. Now you need to copy the string into the buffer.

### UNICODE_STRING init

```c
size_t str_len_no_null = wcslen(SymbolicLinkListPtr); // number of chars, not bytes!
Input.Length = str_len_no_null * sizeof(WCHAR);
size_t max_length_bytes = Input.Length + (1 * sizeof(WCHAR)); // add room for possible null.
Input.MaximumLength = max_length_bytes; 
Input.Buffer = (PWSTR) ExAllocatePool2(PagedPool, Input.MaximumLength, 0); // note: you should define a Tag for your Driver.
if(Input.buffer == NULL) {
    // not enough memory.
    return;
}
status = RtlStringCbCopyW(Input.Buffer, max_length_bytes, SymbolicLinkListPtr);
// TODO: check status
```

Now that you know how to do it manually, throw your code and use [`RtlUnicodeStringInit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntstrsafe/nf-ntstrsafe-rtlunicodestringinit)

### Other things & hints

- Always checks the return status / value of the functions you use. In kernel mode, this is super important.
- `NTSTATUS` check is always done using one of the [status macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-ntstatus-values) (usually `NT_SUCCESS`)
- Use [string safe functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/summary-of-kernel-mode-safe-string-functions).
- nitpicking: A success return value of `IoGetDeviceInterfaces` may also indicate an empty buffer. Although you check that in the for loop init-statement, I would have checked that right after the function so the intent is clearer.

```c
KdPrint(("Object name:%s \n", ObjectAtiribute.ObjectName - > Buffer));
```

It's `%S` (wide char) not `%s` (char); see [format specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-170). you can pass a `UNICODE_STRING` and use the `%Z` formatter. Also be wary of `- >` which is strange (you probably meant `->`).

```c
InitializeObjectAttributes( & ObjectAtiribute, SymbolicLinkStr, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, 0, 0);
```

- Use `OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE` if the resulting handle is not meant to cross the kernel <-> user-mode boundary (in your case, it doesn't have to cross that boundary). Otherwise you leak a kernel handle to user-mode, which has security implications.

This is also **required** when you call [`ZwOpenSymbolicLinkObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwopensymboliclinkobject) and you are not running in a system thread:

> If the caller is not running in a system thread context, it must set the OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE attribute when it calls InitializeObjectAttributes.

- You can define GUIDs with `DEFINE_GUID`; see [Defining and Exporting New GUIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/defining-and-exporting-new-guids) and [Including GUIDs in Driver Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/including-guids-in-driver-code). In your case you don't need to export it.
- This is probably nitpicking, but use `nullptr` (c++) or `NULL` (c) instead of 0 to convey the idea that you are checking for a pointer and not just the integral value of 0.

Comment: Thank you very very much for such a detailed answer. I thought I could never get help so I completely changed my method. However that one still has its own problems which is fair to be asked in another post. But in short i used ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile, the problem is i can't find device type with number 0x7, all of storage related devices are 0x8 as a result function returns “The specified request is not a valid operation for the target device.” is it VM related problem?

Comment: @disharm0niz That's a very good question, about which I'm not very sure of what could be the answer. If there are no `FILE_DEVICE_DISK` this means there are no physical disks but just mounted volumes as described by `FILE_DEVICE_DISK_FILE_SYSTEM`. I can't really explain why, it might be that your VMM is using synthetic devices or all requests go through file system redirectors. I'm not knowledgeable enough about this part of the FS to give you a definitive answer. If you haven't any luck on SO, you might try the OSR list.